# Facebook user id on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I have an app on both iOS and Android that has the option to login via Facebook. 
If I register and login from Android, I can use that type of login on every Android device ( just enter Facebook mail and password and login is ok ). If I use the same account on iOS, the register screen appears. Same thing if I first register the account on iOS and then try to use it on Android.
I'm getting different Facebook user ids on the 2 operating systems. On Android I use socialauth from Google, and on iOS I use the details from the integrated Facebook app. 
The id is stored on a server and when an user try to login with Facebook it compares the id with the one stored. 
How can I generate an unique Id both on Android and iOS for the same account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using 2 different Apps. You need to use the exact same App to get the same User ID, you don´t get the global ID anymore but only an "App Scoped ID". Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I fixed this issue by registering the app on https://developers.facebook.com/apps and setting the iOS and Android details. Also I changed to Facebook SDK on both platforms.